# how to iterate through different WITH statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

For privacy reasons, I can't post the entire query, but we have a query that looks like this

```
> WITH datee as (SELECT '2017-06-25 00:00:00-00'::DATE as dateee) SELECT
> tab1.a  FROM (super long query here that references dateee a lot) as tab1
```

I need this to iterate through a range of dates, say from 2017-03-25 00:00:00-00 to 2017-06-25 00:00:00-00.

Is there a way to automate it without having to run the query one date at the time?

Comment: Well you could expand your CTE to include more dates (using `UNION ALL`) or you could [generate a set of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400560/postgresql-using-with-clause-to-iterate-over-a-range-of-dates).

Comment: Much better to use a `VALUES` clause than `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

Use `generate_series(startdate, enddate, interval)`

```
SELECT generate_series(DATE '2017-06-25', DATE '2017-08-01', INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

Or if it's a set of unrelated dates, use a values expression

```
WITH datee as (VALUES ('2017-06-25'), ('2017-08-14')) 
SELECT
```

or (easier to generat from some tools or languages) pass an array to unnest:

```
WITH datee(datee) as (SELECT unnest($1))
```

where `$1` a bind parameter of type `date[]`

---

You may also be better off using your input as a clause in `FROM` not a CTE (`WITH` query) due to a [deficiency in PostgreSQL's CTE support](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/). So

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
  SELECT unnest($1)
) AS datee(datee)
```

except that in this case you can further simplify with a `LATERAL` join to

```
SELECT ..
FROM (super long query) ...
     LATERAL unnest($1) AS dateee(datee)
```

which will likely perform best.